# Please tell me what drupal table the block php visibilities settings is stored at

Tags: blocks

Within a block I have configured under the "Visibility settings" and "Show block on specific pages" I have put in PHP code that determines where this block is displayed within a page or not via a returned true or false.
I have it working correctly but then I added additional restrictions within the PHP but I must have put in a syntax error that caused the site to go down saying "Temporarily Unavailable".

I need to be able to change the PHP code back to the working version but I don't know what drupal table the block PHP code is stored.  Please tell me what drupal table the block php visibilities settings is stored at.

Comment: What version of Drupal is this?

Comment: Drupal 7 is the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php code should be stored in the *pages* field of the *block* table, and it should not be serialized.

The *visibility* field can have one of three values:

- BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED (0),
- BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED (1), or
- BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP (2).

In the case of the first two, the *pages* field will contain a text list of the notlisted or listed pages for the block. in the case of the third, the field will contain the php code.

Comment: And what is the name of the table exactly in Drupal 8?  `block_content_field_data`?